# titleLabel.textColor for Uibutton

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton

In the tableView footer I have a button

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UIView *mainView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 39)];
    [mainView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    UIButton *themebutton= [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    themebutton.backgroundColor= [UIColor redColor];
    [themebutton.layer setCornerRadius:5.8f];
    themebutton.frame= CGRectMake(15, 0, 172, 39);
    [themebutton setTitle:@"Create New" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [themebutton setTitle:@"Create New" forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [themebutton setTitle:@"Create New" forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    themebutton.titleLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Raleway" size:19.8];

    themebutton.titleLabel.textColor=UIColorFromRGB(0x707070);

    [mainView addSubview:themebutton];
    return mainView;
}
```

I have put the titleLabel.textColor as grey but when I click on that button it always convert the text color to white . Why this happening can anyone help me .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set the color depending on the state, for example:

```
[themebutton setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[themebutton setTitleColor:[UIColor greenColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

This will display the label red, and when pressed it will turn green.